# python pandas dataframe cell updating error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a dataframe. When trying to update cells, all updated cell values are zero. This is my code:

```
for column in data:

    if column != "id" and column != "diagnosis":
        # change the dtype to 'float64' 
        data[column] = data[column].astype("float")
        columnArray = data[column].values 
        column_max = max(columnArray)
        column_min = min(columnArray)
        print(column_max, " ", column_min,column)
        for index in range(columnArray.shape[0]):
            cell_value = columnArray[index]
            new_value = (cell_value-column_min)/(column_max-column_min) 
            # print(new_value)
            data.at[index,column] = new_value
```

I also should mention that I am a little bit new to pandas and NumPy and that there might be a built-in function that normalizes my features without any pain.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do any of the for loops:

```
columns = ~data.columns.isin(['id', 'diagnosis'])
data.loc[:, columns] = (data.loc[:, columns] - data.loc[:, columns].min()) / (data.loc[:, columns].max() - data.loc[:, columns].min())
```

Comment: again all the values is zero except for one value in each column(which is the maximum value that have been normalized to 1) , the column  datatypes are float

Comment: Can you post example input, output and desired output data?

Comment: I will do that in a moment

Comment: it was dummy mistake , my Spyder variable explorer was set to digit format, it was Spyder variable explorer that round down the values,by the way tanks bro for your help , your code is simple and beautiful